# Android navigation drawer load default fragment on initial load

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, android-xml

I am working on a project with navigation drawer.
I am using a function for loading home fragment. But the app on initial load loading another fragment rather than home fragment. Here my code is.

**MainActivity.java**

```
 Runnable mPendingRunnable = () -> {
            Fragment fragment = getFragment();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(android.R.anim.fade_in, android.R.anim.fade_out);
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.nav_host_fragment_content_main, fragment, CURRENT_TAG);
            fragmentTransaction.commitAllowingStateLoss();
        };
```

I want the home fragment loaded first and different fragment on selected from menu. Kindly help me.

Comment: Are you using `FrameLayout` or `androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView`

Comment: @kamalNayan No, I am not using.

Comment: What are you using ?? To show fragments.